# Can't seem to process JSON response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response from the Amazon API which responds as follows:

```
    {
  "Result": {
    "Data": {
      "Title": "HALO 3 (XBOX 360 - REGION FREE)",
      "FormattedPrice": "$19.95",
      "Source": "Product Description",
      "Content": "The epic saga continues..."
    }
  }
}
```

In my Javascript code I keep getting undefined when trying to access the FormattedPrice.

I've tried various versions of this:

```
var price1 = Response.Result.Data.FormattedPrice;

var price1 = Response.Result[0].Data[0].FormattedPrice;

var price1 = Response.Result[0].FormattedPrice;
```

Added full call code:

data.name = Halo 3. Changed Response to PriceResponse

```
//Load Amazon Price data
                 var setUrl =
                "https://example.com/price.php?q="+encodeURI(data.name)+"&output=json";
            console.log(setUrl);
            jQuery.getJSON(setUrl, function(priceResponse) {

                var price1 = Response.Result[0].Data[0].FormattedPrice;



                    jQuery("#info-link-amazon").append('<span style="float:right;">$'+price1+'</span>');   




            });
```

Comment: has the JSON already been parsed?

Comment: 1) Not good to name your variable a global one (`Response`). 2) Make sure it's *parsed*, and debug like you would any other thing: log the value and type of your variable

Comment: If I try to parse the response I get the following error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data.

Comment: can you post the code that gets the data and the one that parses it?

Comment: Added now for you! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, debug the code using developer tools of your browser. Whatch priceResponse value after getJSON call has completed, and verify (on network tab) that the response of the call is what you expect. Then, based on your published response yet, the access to response must be with priceResponse variable:

```
//Load Amazon Price data
var setUrl = "https://example.com/price.php?q="+encodeURI(data.name)+"&output=json";
console.log(setUrl);
jQuery.getJSON(setUrl, function(priceResponse) {
    var price1 = priceResponse.Result.Data.FormattedPrice;
});
```

Comment: And what's the error that you receive first. Basing on your code, there's no variable called "Response", I republish the response in order to what I think you expect.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and it worked perfectly. I honestly feel like I did that and it returned undefined but I may not have given it enough time to properly refresh. Thank you!